# How do I output a dropdown's values if I'm on a registration form not tied to an entry?

Tags: users, field, drop-down

I have a registration form on my website. All of the fields here so far have been text, which is no problem. However, I've just been asked to create a dropdown box for users to select their salutation (mr, mrs, doctor etc).

I've created the field in the backend and linked it to Users, and I can update it through a front-end form no problem using the value="users/saveUser" method, and pulling the values using currentUser.salutation.options. However, when registering, I can't output the values like that as the user isn't signed in (because they're registering), so there is no currentUser. I can't use the documentation code:

```
{% for option in entry.dropdownFieldHandle.options %}
    <li>{{ option }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

as there is no entry, I'm just on a template with a registration form on it. How do I output the dropdown options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The not so elegant way to do this is to re-use the field somewhere else, where you do have access to (e.g. a global set). But you probably want to avoid this, right?

What you can do instead is to access the field directly using [`craft.fields`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.fields). This function returns the FieldModel of your field, containing all of its properties. The FieldModel property you want is `attributes.settings`, where you can access your dropdown `options` like this:

```
{% set dropdownField = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('dropdownFieldHandle') %}

{% for option in dropdownField.settings.options %}
    {{ option.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. So glad there's a way to grab a field even when it's not part of the entry!