# How do I print the options in a dropdown field?

Tags: templating

I have a dropdown field with X options.  I want to print each option as a button.

I tried...

```
<ul>
    {% for option in entry.isotope.options %}
        <li>{{ option }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

isotope = dropdownFieldHandle

But I get the error `Variable "entry" does not work'`.

Comment: Are you actually trying to call this in an ``entry`` template? ``entry`` won't [automatically](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing) get created by Craft if you're on a ``category`` or custom route, for example.

Comment: No, I am not in the entry template.  I tried  using set to entry in craft.entries.section('posts'), but that just printed out the title of all the entries instead of the handful of options in the dropdown field.

Comment: That's your problem. Which post are you actually trying to get? When you call ``craft.entries`` you're going to get a group of entries back based on the parameters you specify. You might try something like ``{% set entry = craft.entries.section('posts').slug('post-with-isotope-options')[0] %}`` to get just one entry.

Comment: But I don't want the entries.  I just want to print the options in the field dropdown.

Comment: Gotcha, couple ways to do that, see answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not an "elegant" way to do this but you can access the dropdown field by its handle using `getFieldByHandle`. Something like:

```
{% set dropdownField = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('isotope') %}

  {% for option in dropdownField.settings.options %}
    <li>{{ option.value }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```

If you need the label instead, just use `{{ option.label }}`

You can also grab a dropdown's options from any entry you know has the field already attached, such as the first entry from your `news` section for example:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('news').limit(1)[0] %}

<ul>
{% for option in  entry.isotope.options %}
    <li>{{ option.value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note: similar to [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/how-do-i-output-a-dropdowns-values-if-im-on-a-registration-form-not-tied-to-an) question.

Comment: Your first approach is just what I needed to print the field options into the isotope data-filter.  Thanks.