# How to print all possible options of a dropdown field inside of a Matrix field?

Tags: templating, matrix, field, drop-down

I'm asking this outside an entry context.

My starting point is

> {% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('matrixFieldHandle')
>   %}

When I print the data of the field, I find nothing related to the fields that `matrixFieldHandle` contains.

- `matrixFieldHandle` (Matrix field)

  - Block `Log`

    - Field `logValue` (Dropdown field)

I know how to print the options in a dropdown field:

- [How do I output a dropdown's values if I'm on a registration form not tied to an entry?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/how-do-i-output-a-dropdowns-values-if-im-on-a-registration-form-not-tied-to-an)
- [How do I print the options in a dropdown field?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18853/how-do-i-print-the-options-in-a-dropdown-field)

But how can I print all these dropdown options when it is set inside a Matrix?

Comment: What happens if you loop through field and print field.log?

Comment: I get a Twig Runtime Error: Calling unknown method.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done like so...

```
{% set matrix = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('myMatrixField') %}
{% for field in matrix.blockTypeFields if field.handle=='myDropdownField'  %}
    <select>
    {% for option in field.options %}
        <option value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endfor %}
```